# make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.o] Error 1

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, caffe

I'm trying to install caffe on ubuntu but I'm getting errors.

root@c8f75a5e7268:/work/caffe# make all

PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto

CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc

CXX src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cpp

In file included from ./include/caffe/common.hpp:19:0,

from ./include/caffe/blob.hpp:8,

from ./include/caffe/net.hpp:10,

from ./include/caffe/solver.hpp:7,

from ./include/caffe/sgd_solvers.hpp:7,

from src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cpp:4:

./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:34:23: fatal error: cublas_v2.h: No 
such file or directory

compilation terminated.

Makefile:591: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.o' failed

make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.o] Error 1